# having trouble with my list category posts plugin

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

I'm using the list-category-posts on this page: http://www.goldcoastchamber.com/member-directory/ to pull in the links to all the posts under the member-directory category. That part is working, but for some reason it's not putting them in alphabetical ascending order, even though I used that argument, as you can see here:

`[catlist name=member-directory, orderby=title, order=ASC, numberposts=-1]`

please advise why this is not working. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure but i think you don't need to use commas , so try

```
[catlist name=member-directory orderby=title order=ASC numberposts=-1]
```

Comment: I was getting ready to suggest that. I didn't think he needed the commas anyway.

Comment: Yeah, commas are not needed for the WordPress shortcode API. The plugin is probably ignoring the orderby parameter since it's reading "title," instead of "title". It's strange that the correct categories are being displayed since it's using a comma too, but try using it as בניית אתרים says, and if that doesn't work out well, come back here and let us know.